# How to format a text inside a variable in React using \n or <br/> or similar

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to format a text inside a variable using React. I need to use \n or 
  but it's not working, Also I need to bold the tittles. For example:

const termsAndConditions = "**Terms and Conditions
Welcome to Website Name!**

These terms and conditions outline the rules and regulations for the use of Company Name's Website, located at Website.com.

By accessing this website we assume you accept these terms and conditions. Do not continue to use Website Name if you do not agree to take all of the terms and conditions stated on this page.

The following terminology applies to these Terms and Conditions, Privacy Statement and Disclaimer Notice and all Agreements: “Client”, “You” and “Your” refers to you, the person log on this website and compliant to the Company's terms and conditions. “The Company”, “Ourselves”, “We”, “Our” and “Us”, refers to our Company. “Party”, “Parties”, or “Us”, refers to both the Client.

**Cookies**

We employ the use of cookies. By accessing Website Name, you agreed to use cookies in agreement ";

Comment: you can simple use `br`

Comment: for the bold parts use <strong> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use template literals

[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Example without template

```
    console.log('string text line 1\n' +
'string text line 2');
// Output be
// "string text line 1
// string text line 2"
```

Example with template

```
console.log(`string text line 1
string text line 2`);
// Output be
// "string text line 1
// string text line 2"
```

Comment: don't forget to tell him that the `` tags are a key role in how that worked

Comment: I forgeted this it's true

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to use `JSX` you can actually format your content using `HTML`.

Using **Functional Component**:

```js
function TermsAndConditions() {
   return (
      <div>
         <p><strong>Paragraph in bold</stron></p>
         <p>Normal paragraph</p>
      </div>
   );
}

function Footer() {
   return <TermsAndConditions/>
};

ReactDOM.render(
   <Footer/>,
   document.getElementById('footer')
);
```

Or using **Class Component**:

```js
function TermsAndConditions() {
   return (
      <div>
         <p><strong>Paragraph in bold</stron></p>
         <p>Normal paragraph</p>
      </div>
   );
}

class Footer extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         {this.props.message}
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Footer message={<TermsAndConditions/>}/>,
   document.getElementById('footer')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using CSS.

```
.white-space-pre-line {
  white-space: pre-line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this using CSS.
>
> .white-space-pre-line {   white-space: pre-line }

I found that using a different style worked for my needs

```
.white-space-pre-wrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```